# mail function $headers display name doesn't work if email address is .co.uk

Tags: php, email, email-headers

I have the following headers configuration:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Student Portal <admin@student-portal.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: Student Portal <admin@student-portal.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
mail ($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

This works fine but it doesn't display the display name assigned "Student Portal" instead it just shows the e-mail address. If I change the extension of the email address to ".com", the display names appears on email successfully.

I'm thinking it's something to do with escaping the second "." in the ".co.uk" but I'm not sure how to do that. How do I get a display name like "Student Portal" to work with a .co.uk address?

Comment: The header itself looks well formed. You're seeing this in an email client somewhere?

Comment: This is sounding like an outlook issue to me, that you have a record in contacts (or in the local cache) that is causing the line to display the email address instead of the name being provided by the headers. I've had this 'problem' when working with the Outlook address book, usually you can remove the cached version of the contact to resolve the issue.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll have a look at this.

Comment: You may want to check out [superuser](http://superuser.com/) for Outlook help.